# Missing assembly when using VisualSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, gac, visualsvn

I have installed VisualSVN through VisualStudio Marketplace on a MS Visual Studio 2017. I am using a Windows 10 Pro host.

When I right-click on a file and select "Show differences", I have the following error message  :

[image]

It could not find Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.interop.dll. I have check in c:\windows\assembly\GAC. The directory is almost empty. It contains only stdole directory. I found the dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.

Is there a way for forcing VS to read in that directory ? Or is there something missing in my configuration ?

Comment: Repair Visual Studio and see whether it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: It worked after repairing VS. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is some problem with your Visual Studio installation. [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) to resolve this issue.